# Overused the capacity memory when trying to process the CSV file when using Pyspark and Python

Tags: excel, csv, memory, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I dont know which part of the code I should share since what I do is basically as below(I will share a simple code algorithm instead for reference):

Task: I need to search for file A and then match the values in file A with column values in File B(It has more than 100 csv files, with each contained more than 1millions rows in CSV), then after matched, combined the results into a single CSV.

1. Extract column values for File A and then make it into list of values.
2. Load File B in pyspark and then use .isin to match with File A list of values.
3. Concatenate the results into single csv file.

"""

```
first = pd.read_excel("fileA.xlsx")
list_values = first[first["columnA"].apply(isinstance,args=(int,))]["columnA"].values.tolist()

combine = []
for file in glob.glob("directory/"): #here will loop at least 100 times. 
    second = spark.read.csv("fileB")
    second = second["columnB"].isin(list_values) # More than hundreds thousands rows will be expected to match. 
    combine.append(second)
    
total = pd.concat(combine)
```

Error after 30hours of running time:

```
 UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
```

Is there a way to better perform such task? currently, to complete the process it takes more than 30hours to just run the code but it ended with failure with above error. Something like parallel programming or which I could speed up the process or to clear the above error? ?

Also, when I test it with running only 2 CSV files, it took less than a minute to complete but when I try to loop the whole folder with 100 files, it takes more than 30hours.

Comment: Could anyone assist me with this.

Comment: can someone help pls.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that I think you can try to optimize given that your configuration and resource unchanged:

1. Repartition when you read your CSV. Didn't study the source code on how spark read the csv, but based on my experience / case in SO, when you use spark to read the csv, all the data will be in single partition, which might cause you the Java OOM error and also it's not fully utilize your resource. Try to check the partitioning of the data and make sure that there is no data skewness before you do any `transformation` and `action`.
2. Rethink on how to do the filtering based on another dataframe column value. From your code, your current approach is to use a python list to collect and store the reference, and then use `.isin()` to search if the main dataframe column contain value which is in this reference list. If the length of your reference list is very large, the searching operation of EACH ROW to go through the whole reference list is definitely a high cost. Instead, you can try to use the leftsemi `.join()` operation to achieve the same goal. Even if the dataset is small and you want to prevent the data shuffling, you can use the `broadcast` to copy your reference dataframe to every single node.
3. If you can achieve in `Spark SQL`, don't do it by `pandas`. In your last step, you're trying to concat all the data after the filtering. In fact, you can achieve the same goal with `.unionAll()` or `.unionByName()`. Even you do the `pd.concat()` in the spark session, all the pandas operation will be done in the driver node but not distributed. Therefore, it might cause Java OOM error and degrade the performance too.